# How to find smallest possible $\alpha$ such that matrix $A+\beta I$ is invertible for all $\beta>\alpha$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

From definition I know, that determinant of invertible matrix is non zero. Determinat of $2\times2$ matrix $A+\beta I$ is $\beta^2+\beta(a+d)+ad-bc\neq0$. I don't know how to proceed from here. Maybe I should use the fact, that eigenvalues of invertible matrix are non zero.

Comment: You may take any $\alpha$ greater than or equal to the spectral radius of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A+\beta I$ is invertible iff $\det(A+\beta I)\ne0$. This determinant is a monic polynomial on $\beta$. So $\alpha$ is the largest root of that polynomial (that is, the largest eigenvalue of $A$). Indeed, if $\beta>\alpha$ then $\det(A+\beta I)>0$.

Comment: Thanks, I just don't know how to find root of a polynomial that's set to be not equal to zero.

Comment: @Dio, it's set to zero. It's just that after the largest root the polynomial is not zero (positive actually).

Comment: So am I right if say that $\beta-\lambda=\alpha$? That's what I got, now I just don't know how to get to the result that $\beta>|\lambda|$